Wrong SceneKit hit testing results in iOS 17.2 compared with iOS 16.1 when using either OpenGLES2 or Metal
We’re experiencing an issue with wrong SceneKit hit testing results in iOS 17.2 compared with iOS 16.1 when using the two mentioned engines. Not sure is anyone has experienced the same issue and is there away to work around this?
Tapping on a 3D model to place a SCNNode
code:
// pointInScene: tapped point
let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(pointInScene, options: nil)

return hitResults.first { $0.node.name?.compare("body") == .orderedSame }


Plz add more details or a simple code example to reproduce this issue

I added the code which was used to work out the hit results. The hit result worldCoordinates was fine with iOS 16 but totally wrong in iOS 17.2

Please add clarification and more details
